# How to Inherit windows forms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, datagridview

I have one main form with controls like datagridview, combobox , textboxes and so on.I have created another which i want to use it as a wizard for selection as am trying to make it look user friendly. Now i want to be able to inherit controls inside the main form. i don't have a class nor create it as i don't wanna use it. i know how to create class and call my class within the form i want to access the method, properties and function.

How can i access the controls from one form to another.

e.g datagridview and textbox are from form1. on form two,i want to be able to access those two controls(datagridview and textbox). Please note here am giving as an example but from my main form i have more that two kinds of control.

My code from the wizard form

```
    private void btnBrosweInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            BrowseFile();
            ReadFile(ref Gridview_Input, 
            ref txtInputfile, 
            ref cboLanguage, 
            bref btnNewfile);

      //Errors that m getting from this method
     1.Gridview_Input' does not exist in the current context
     2.The best overloaded method match for    .FrmExisitngFile.ReadFile(ref System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView, ref System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, ref System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, ref System.Windows.Forms.Button)' has some invalid arguments
     3.Error    5   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref Gridview_Input' to 'ref System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'


    }
```

I have place this method for readfile on the form

```
       private void ReadFile(ref DataGridView _Grid, ref TextBox _InputTexBox, ref ComboBox _cboLanguage, ref  Button _btnNew)
    {
        _Grid.Rows.Clear();
        string PathSelection = ""; 
        if (_InputTexBox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            PathSelection = _InputTexBox.Text;
        }
        oDataSet = new DataSet();          
        XmlReadMode omode = oDataSet.ReadXml(PathSelection);

        for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            string font = Between(comment, "[Font]", "[/Font]");
            string datestamp = Between(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
            string commentVal = Between(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");

            string[] row = new string[] { oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(), oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(), font, datestamp, commentVal };
            _Grid.Rows.Add(row);
            _btnNew.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

from the wizard form am trying to access the controls from the main form which contains the grid where everything will get loaded on

Comment: so do you just want to access other form's controls ? just declare a variable from that form in form2 and access what you want through that variable and set it in the constructor to be the form1 variable created in main function

Comment: Can you please show me in coding just to give me a highlight?

Comment: can you explain your exact goal , what will form1 have ? what does it do ? and what will form2 have ? what does it do and what will it do with the form1's controls ?

Comment: niceman I think he just wants to know (and I quote:) _"How can i access the controls from one form to another."_

Comment: @ GrawCube  i want to apply that. not just to know

Comment: @GrawCube but the answer depends on the goal, for instance he might want to only show form2 if form1 is shown or maybe he doesn't want that, maybe all he want is a dialog form in which he doesn't need to have two form classes

Comment: Where is the 'inheritance' here? Please adjust your Title and Tags.

Comment: You can simply make the controls `public` (in the properties window) but you are asking us to help in a very bad design. A Form is a View, it shouldn't have to access another View (so directly).

Comment: Ad iirc, the DataGridView doesn't support inheritance, at least not in the designer.

Comment: I have main form which contains datagridview,combobox,textbox and two buttons. (from all those controls i have mentioned. the user will browse the file and it will get loaded to the datagridview,the user will select the language from the combobox and now i have decided to create a wizard which the user will use.

Comment: You don't want to manipulate the controls of `Form1` in `Form2`, do you? What you really want is to manipulate the underlying data. Just pass those data in the constructor of `Form2`. Keep them in class fields so that you'll be able to access them anywhere inside the class. Then make sure you have proper databinding or refreshing plugged into `Form1` to reflect the changes when you close your wizard.

Comment: based on the text I still don't have a clue what you want and if your really need inheritance.

Comment: Patrice Gahide ; exactly what i want to do. but when i browse the file and click done it doesn't get loaded. can you please show me in coding, i don't know how i can do it

Comment: This is still not clear what part exactly you get wrong. You mean that `Form1` doesn't get updated when the wizard is done? Please edit your initial post with your code.

Comment: Patrice Gahide can you add me on my skaype account "enos.sitholimela" ?

Comment: @JuniorSD Well I think that if you make the effort to post meaningful code, everyone here will be disposed to help you. No need for a Skype session, plus it is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: owk let me post my coding from my question

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for why and how to post a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example that illustrates your question. Be sure to explain what you've tried, what the code does now, and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things going on in your code, but the main problem is that you try to manipulate data from your UI controls. This is a tremendously bad idea and it dramatically complicates your design (as you can already see from this fairly small feature).

As I stated in the OP's comments, you don't want to manipulate the controls to work with data. You want to manipulate data from POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects). And then update (or better: databind) all the controls that *expose* those data.

So you should start by doing something like this:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
  private List<Things> _listOfThings;
  private string _inputText;
  private LanguageEnum _lang;
  ...

  // Receives data, NOT controls! 
  public Form2(List<Things> listOfThings, string inputText, LanguageEnum lang, ...)
  {
    _listOfThings = listOfThings;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Your `Form1` reflects the state of `listOfThings` via a `DataGridView`, `inputText` via a `TextBox` and so on. You get the idea. `Form1` pass those data (NOT the controls) to `Form2` via constructor injection:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(listOfThings, inputTextBox.Text, ...);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

You read and update the data using the private fields in the `Form2` class. When `Form2` is closed, you update `Form1`'s controls, either explicitly or using [Databinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @JuniorSD Well of course, this code is not intended to be copy-pasted as it is. It is just an illustration of the general idea, the intend is to get you started on the right track. It's your job then to make it work for your own needs. If you have a specific problem, edit your question with the details, or post another question if it isn't really related to this one.